# Intellij IDEA. Run unit test even if project doesn't compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How I can run unit test for class if other classes (not related to unit-tested class) doesn't compile?

Comment: Disable *Make* option in the Run configuration. Compile files using the **Compile** action from the context menu.

Comment: I would make sure your program at least compiles before worrying about anything else.  Eclipse has this feature and I consider it a very bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

In the Run\Debug configuration, you can remove the option: Before launch - make.